# Java rest api test generic

Tags: java, rest

I am very new to the rest api. I saw a lot of answers and checked on google but I couldn't make it work.
I have installed netbeans 8.2, Java jdk1.8.0_111, downloaded apache-tomcat-10.0.2.
I am trying to create a simple rest services. I have created a maven web project, tested the index.xhtm, it is opening. Than I have tried to create a Rest from patterns and it automatically creates the Application Config and Generic.
When I try to test I get  the unable to open resource url http://localhost:8080/mavenproject5.
The context xml file

the generic resource class

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author home
 */
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of GenericResource
     */
    public GenericResource() {
    }
}
```

the index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Start Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the pom dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
<version>7.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Tomcat does not provide a JAX-RS implementation. You need to add e.g. Jersey to your project. Also Tomcat 10 uses the new `jakarta` namespace instead of `javax`. If you want to use Tomcat 10 you need Jersey 3 and replace all `javax` imports with `jakarta`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll change it to Tomcat 9 and add jersey

Comment: [Jersey 2.33](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.33) is the last version, which works with Tomcat 9. Also, since Tomcat does not implement all Java EE APIs, it is better to remove `javaee-web-api` from the dependencies: add just those [provided by Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) out of the box.

Comment: My depensencies look like:'<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.33</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>' after I downloaded the apache 9.0.43-windows-x64 and I have the same issue

Comment: But I changed the tomcat with the glassfish server and now on righ click I can test and it is opening the page with the returned String from the same method.

Comment: Hi Piotr, can you please let me know what dependency do I have to ad for the org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition? Thank you

Comment: Glassfish is a full Java EE container, it has JAX-RS out-of-the-box. For Tomcat you also need to add [jersey-container-servlet](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.33) so that Jersey can register with the Servlet Container. You can find a description of all optional Jersey modules (including the multipart module) in [Jersey documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#modules).

Comment: A lot of thanks Piotr. Very good explication. In the end I used glassfish. Thanks again.